# RoR - Forum_Monster Demo site - undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum

I have downloaded and I am running localy the demo application for the gem "Forum_monster"
I have not done anything to it but when I post a from either admin or user account I get:

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):

14:       <% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
15:       <tr>
16:         <td class="post_author" rowspan="2">
17:           <span class="name"><%= post.user.username %></span>
18:           <br />
19:           <br />
20:           <span class="info smaller">
```

I cannot find where to fix this error. All the code is exactly the same as on github. [forum_monster git](https://github.com/gitt/forum_monster_demo)

Comment: did you do every step exactly as described, with no resulting errors?

Comment: Check your DB. Is there a record for the post you made, and does that post have a not-nil field for user?

Comment: yes, I did everything as described

Comment: my user table has a username, my topics and post tables have user id's in them

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem.
I was using devise 1.1.rc0, by default it didn't give the option to set the username.

This railscast explain how to set a username.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?autoplay=true